# Center a line of two words on the space separating them

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have this document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\centerline{onlyoneword}
\centerline{sveeeeeeeeeerylongword \qquad shortword}


\end{document}
```

I want to center the line on the `\qquad`. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do this in a tabular set up like this: `\begin{tabular}{r @{\qquad} l} veeeeeeeerylongword & shortword\\ \end{tabular}` Everything in that table will be centered on the `\qquad`. But I don't know how to center the `\qquad` relative to the page.

Comment: Relative to typeblock or physical page?

Comment: I believe `\centerline` is a macro from the Plain TeX format, not LaTeX. Better to use `\centering` or a `center` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make boxes. And never use `\centerline` in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the text block margins

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{onlyoneword}\\*
\makebox[\dimexpr.5\textwidth-1em][r]{sveeeeeeeeeerylongword}%
\qquad
\makebox[\dimexpr.5\textwidth-1em][l]{shortword}

% just to have an indicator of the middle of the page
\medskip
\noindent\hfill\vrule height 5pt\hfill\mbox{}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could consider setting the text inside a full-width [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). This allows you to have line-breaks (and/or paragraphs) inside the respective cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{\qquad}X@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{onlyoneword} \\
  \raggedleft sveeeeeeeeeerylongword & shortword
\end{tabularx}

% just to have an indicator of the middle of the page
\medskip
\noindent\hfill\vrule height 5pt\hfill\mbox{}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength\mysep \setlength{\mysep}{20pt}%
\newcommand\usemysep{\hspace*{\mysep}}%
\newcommand\hangcenter[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \par
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#1\usemysep}%
  \usemysep x\usemysep
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usemysep #2}%
  \par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Regular text.

\begin{center}
I want to center the line on the qquad. Is it possible?
I want to center the line on the qquad. Is it possible?
I want to center the line on the qquad. Is it possible?

  AAA

\end{center}

Regular text.

Regular text.

\hangcenter{This is much longer.}{Short}
Regular text.

\end{document}
```